# npm install -g expo-cli , installation error

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-cache

I install npm to create my react-native project by using following command

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

but unfortunately i can't install it. it gives following error.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\kkawm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\@expo\xdl-f252ea11\binaries\linux\adb\adb
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\kkawm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\@expo\xdl-f252ea11\binaries\linux\adb\adb'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\kkawm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\@expo\xdl-f252ea11\binaries\linux\adb\adb'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\kkawm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\@expo\xdl-f252ea11\binaries\linux\adb\adb'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\kkawm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\@expo\\xdl-f252ea11\\binaries\\linux\\adb\\adb'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\kkawm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\.staging\\@expo\\xdl-f252ea11\\binaries\\linux\\adb\\adb',
npm ERR!   parent: 'expo-cli'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kkawm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-03T05_57_40_929Z-debug.log
```

How I solve this error?

Comment: Well, you probably had a none completed installation before, so the dependency links got broken, you have to use `npm install` once then try to install `expo-cli` afterwards.

Comment: May be this is permission related issue. Try using `sudo npm install -g expo-cli `.

Comment: @KishanBharda sudo is not working for me. i'm working on windows operating system

Comment: Ohh sorry. So give permission manually to the folder.

Comment: have you tried running cli as administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install npm using `npm install`but it gives following warnings.

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\ucsc\3rd year\Mobile Application Development\lec. notes\abc\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\ucsc\3rd year\Mobile Application Development\lec. notes\abc\package.json'
npm WARN abc No description
npm WARN abc No repository field.
npm WARN abc No README data
npm WARN abc No license field.

up to date in 1.557s
```

hence I use `npm install -g npm`. it installed sucessfully

after i install expo-cli using `npm install -g expo-cli`
it installed sucessfully

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install -g expo-cli` from a terminal